# How to show the previous running eclipse 4 rcp application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

When the user clicks on exe icon again as of now i am using checking if the location isset and is it locked if yes i am throwing an error message. Is there a way to show the previously running application in eclipe 4 rcp

Comment: You need to be more precise with your question. Which location do you mean? What do you mean "is set" and locked?

Comment: Location instanceLocation = Platform.getInstanceLocation(); this is the location object which i use to check isset and lock. this location object is fetched when the framework sends the @ProcessAdditions. Can you please tell if there is a way to show the active application

Comment: So you want to know whether or not the current application is already running?

Comment: i can know if there is an application already running by doing instanceLocation.isLocked(). But how can i show that application is my question ?. in eclipse 3.x i think this can be achieved by using  http://random-eclipse-tips.blogspot.in/2009/07/eclipse-rcp-single-instance-of-rcp.html